# How can I edit metadata and custom fields for an embedded image using Media Module in a WYSIWYG in D7

Tags: 7, media, wysiwyg

I need the ability to edit custom fields (Caption, Credit) on an image that has been placed in a WYSIWYG. I'm using the latest dev version of the media module and WYSIWYG + CKeditor. I see the fields fine when I add the image, but when I click the media button to edit the image, the custom fields are not accessible.

Adding an image works, but only if you upload a new image. 
[image: Adding works]

Editing does not show the fields though.
[image: Editing does not work]

This seemingly was solved a long time ago... but doesn't seem to be part of the latest dev branch. 
https://www.drupal.org/node/835516#comment-7537339

[image: I'm looking for something like this]

Any direction on how to get the custom file fields to display and be editable with D7?

Comment: I asked Dave Reid on the Drupal slack channel and he recommended that I look into media_ckeditor

https://www.drupal.org/project/media_ckeditor since the ckeditor integration was split off into that module, so that’s where the code would be I think. Either that or the media_wysiwyg sub-module in media.

Comment: media_ckeditor is meant to work with Ckeditor (standalone module), I'm not sure if/how it works with WYSIWYG module + Ckeditor

Comment: This thread may be of use https://www.drupal.org/node/2731335

Comment: Yeah, I ended up getting rid of the WYSIWYG and swapping it out with the CKEditor (standalone module). I'm still not seeing any of my custom fields when editing an embedded image though using

        "drupal/media_ckeditor": "dev-2.x",
        "drupal/ckeditor": "^1.17"


And v4.6.2 of the ckeditor js library. 

Thanks for the thread though. That looks like it might be related, although doesn't seem to really address the custom image field entities in the WYSIWYG from what I see so far.

Answer (score 1):

After a tremendous amount of research and trial & error, I was finally able to figure this out. The "trick" is to make sure you click the "override in WYSIWYG" checkbox on the file field at `/admin/structure/file-types/manage/image/fields/field_caption`

[image]